# Mean Value Theorem Answers wrong??

Tags: calculus

Ok so I have a problem that I know satisfies all the rules of the mean value theorem, and I have to find "c" that satisfies the conclusion of the mean value theorem, and everything I do I can only get one answer ( 1/3 ) but the online submission form says I'm doing something wrong and won't accept the answer! Any suggestions? Here is the problem below:

$$ f(x) = 3x^2 − 2x + 1 $$
On the interval $$[0, 2] $$

and the answer I keep getting by taking the derivative and solving for X is

$$ 1/3 $$

Please help!
Thank you :)

Comment: How did you get $1/3$?

Comment: derived then solved for x

Comment: Solved for $x$ in what equation?

Comment: did i do it wrong?

Comment: derivitive of 3x^2-2x+1 or 6x-2

Comment: That's not an equation.

Comment: You were solving for the root of 6x-2

Comment: Don't set $f'(c)=0$ set $f'(c)=\text{value MVT gives you}$

Comment: If you set that equal to $0$ and solving for $x$, then you found a critical point. This, a priori, has nothing to do with MVT.

Comment: You are solving $f'(x)=0$.  That is not what the MVT says!

Comment: @David $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: got it! thank you guys!

Comment: @user142299 typo, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2-0}=\frac{9-1}{2}=4$$ So solve $$f'(c)=6c-2=4$$ to get $$c=1$$

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh i see, thank you! i was setting 6c-2 to 0, i see what i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

MVT says:$f(2) - f(0) = f'(c)(2 - 0)$ translates $9 - 1 = 2(6c - 2)$. So$4 = 6c - 2$, and $c = 1$